# if request.method == "POST" return false

Tags: django, django-forms

When sending a POST request to the following
views.py request.method == "POST" return false value

````
    title = 'Update'
    posts = get_object_or_404(post, id=id)
    form = postForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=posts)
    author = get_Author(request.user)
    print(request.FILES == "POST")
    print(form.errors)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = author
            
            form.save()
        return redirect(reverse("postPage", kwargs={
            'id' :form.instance.id
        }))```
````

Comment: how do you make POST request to this view? log out request.method and see whats output?

Comment: request.method == "POST" return false

Comment: Are you talking about the line `print(request.FILES == "POST")` printing `False`?

Comment: Yes and print(form.errors) line not return anything

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the user instance and save the form. you can remove this section `author = get_Author(request.user)` and do this. Guess your user field in you Post model is author.

```
if form.is_valid():
   get_user = form.save(commit=False)
   get_user.author = request.user
   get_user.save()
```